# CSS width dependency of icon and div elements inside of a section

Tags: html, css

Can someone explain to me, why when I set a width to the `div` tag, the width of the `i` icon is as I defined, but when I don't set a width to the `div` tag, the width of the icon is unpredictable?

The width of the icon is also changing depending on the length of the text of the paragraph.

(The `section` is inside a `main` tag in the body)

```css
.about {
  display: flex;
}

.about div {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

main {
  height: 100%;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
}
```

```html
<section class="about">
  <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-user"></i>
  <div>
    <h5>more text</h5>
    <p>
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Odio iure fugit, illum quasi in, amet, iste id voluptatem exercitationem atque numquam aliquam libero saepe laboriosam impedit! Debitis, ipsa. Ducimus, deleniti?
    </p>
  </div>
</section>
```

Comment: I want to assume that using `flex` is what's causing this behavior, which is innately inherited by the `icon` element.

Comment: You are right, it's because the section styled as ```flex```. Do you know why its matter? any idea how to fix it?

Comment: flex-shrink:0 to the icon